# Capturing parts of an absolute filepath in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm writing a class that parses a filename. I've got 3 questions:

#### The regex

Given `hello/this/is/my/page.html` I want to capture three parts:

- The parent folders: `hello/this/is/my`
- The filename itself: `page`
- The extension: `.html`

This is the regex: `/^((?:[^\/]+\/)*)(\w+)(\.\w+)$/`

*The problem is* that when I tried this (using [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)), when I use a relative pathfile such as `page.html`, it all gets captured into the first capturing group.

Can someone suggest a regex that works correctly for both relative and absolute filepaths?

#### The class

Would this class be ok?

```
class RegexFilenameHelper
    filenameRegex = /^((?:[^\/]+\/)*)(\w+)(\.\w+)$/

    def self.getParentFolders(filePath)
        matchData = filenameRegex.match(filePath)
        return matchData[1]
    end

    def self.getFileName(filePath)
        # ...
    end

    def self.getFileExtension(filePath)
        # ...
    end
end
```

I understand that it's inefficient to call `.match` for every function, but I don't intend to use all three functions sequentially.
I also intend to call the class itself, and not instantiate an object.

#### An aside

Assuming this is important: would you rather capture `.html` or `html`, and why?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a regex for this? It seems that [`Pathname`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) or [`File`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html) might be better suited.

Comment: You're right, that seems to be the best way to go around it :p. I'll just take the functions that I want and compile an answer myself.

Comment: here is a regex that matches the path, and the extension in 2 groups:
    (\..*$)|^.*/

Comment: Thanks! but I wanted to match the 3 groups I mentioned, and that regex (while small and tidy) also seems to include the extension in the path capture, I think...

Comment: Nevermind, tried it in Rubular and works exactly as you said! Edited yours and got `((?:^.*\/)?)(\w+)(\..*$)`, which I believe is what I wanted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using the standard library:

As Tim Pietzcker suggested, the functionality is already implemented in the Pathname and File classes.

`filepath = "hello/this/is/my/page.html"`

- Getting the parents: `File.dirname(filepath)` *=> "hello/this/is/my"*
- Getting the name: `File.basename(filepath)` *=> "page.html"*
- without extension: `File.basename(filepath, File.extname(filepath))` *=> "page"*
- Getting the extension: `File.extname(filepath)` *=> ".html"*

We call class methods without having to instantiate any class, which is exactly what I wanted.

*It's not necessary* for the file or folders to actually *exist* in the file system!

Thanks to Tim Pietzcker for letting me know!

---

### Using regex:

If I had wanted to do it with regex, the correct regex would be `((?:^.*\/)?)([^\/]+)(\..*$)`.

- `((?:^.*\/)?)`: Captures everything before the last `/`, or nothing (that's what the last ? is for). This is the parent path, which is optional.
- `([^\/]+)`: Gets everything that's not `/`, which is the filename.
- `(\..*$)`: Captures everything coming after the last `.`, including it.

I tried this in [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) and it worked like a charm, but I'm *still not sure* if the second capturing group is too broad, so be careful if you use this!

Thanks to user230910 for helping me get there! :)